# How can I send a bank wire from X to buy bitcoins?

Tags: exchanges, buy-bitcoins

I want to have some bitcoin too, but I am currently living in Morocco, so where can I change my Dollars and Euros to bitcoins and still can use them worldwide? is there a market for that

Answer (score 3):

If you can send an International (USD) bank wire then you can buy bitcoins at exchanges that accept that method.  This includes Mt. Gox, BITSPEND, Bitcoin-Central, and others.  The fees for sending International wire are generally considered too high to justify when sending smaller amounts of funds (e.g., $1K range or less).

- http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Buying_bitcoins

If you can send a SEPA (EUR) bank transfer then you can buy bitcoins from the exchanges that accept that method instead.  SEPA transfers are generally fairly inexpensive to send.   These market exchanges include Mt. Gox, BITSPEND, Bitcoin-Central, BTC-e as well as many other fixed-rate exchanges including Bitcoins In Berlin. Bitcoin.de, Bitcoin Nordic, Instawire, and more.

If there is an exchange in your country that accepts domestic bank transfers then that may be the least expensive method of moving funds to an exchange.  For instance, Canadian users have the option of using bill payment from a bank to add funds to their exchange account at the Canadian exchange VirWoX at a low cost relative to International bank wire costs.